# Can i use domain name for oauth2 client id?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm working on a OAuth2 server project. Can I use domain name for generating client_id ?

Ex: For instance if Google registering an app in my server, then the client_id will be `google.com`

Am i allowed to use dots in client_id? Is it wise to use domain as client_id ? what are the drawbacks?

According to [Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.2)

> The authorization server issues the registered client a client
> identifier -- a unique string representing the registration
> information provided by the client.  The client identifier is not a
> secret; it is exposed to the resource owner and MUST NOT be used
> alone for client authentication.  The client identifier is unique to
> the authorization server.
>
> The client identifier string size is left undefined by this
> specification.  The client should avoid making assumptions about the
> identifier size.  The authorization server SHOULD document the size
> of any identifier it issues.